# How can I resolve the issue "Websocket connection to wss mysite failed on my chrome

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, godaddy-api

I am having the issue with my websocket. It works well locally on my computer, but when I run with my nginx server on chrome, I get the error

[image: Image of my error on chrome]

Do i have to configure my nodejs server with my ssl key? Here's what I have so far:

```
const app = express()
const httpServer = http.createServer(app)

const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET, POST'],
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ['custom-header'],
  },
})
```

I got my ssl from godaddy, and it contains 3 files. How can i do this?

NGINX SERVER

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain + .com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://mydomain + .com/$1 permanent;
}


server {
       

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

     

        root /var/www/html;

        
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      
        server_name mydomain + .com;
        ssl_certificate /home/chained.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /home/mykey.key;

// React Setup
        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
  
  // NODEJS SETUP
  location /api {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }
  // SOCKET.IO SETUP
   location /socket.io/  {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
  
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
  
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      }
}
```

This is where I set up the REACT SOCKET.IO CODE

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!socket.current) {
      socket.current = io(process.env.REACT_APP_API)
      console.log('SOCKET', socket.current)
    }

    if (socket.current) {
      socket.current.emit('join', { userId: user._id })

      socket.current.on('connectedUsers', ({ users }) => {
        users.length > 0 &&
          dispatch({
            type: 'SET_CONNECTED_USERS',
            payload: users,
          })
        // users.length > 0 && setConnectedUsers(users)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Hi, add your nginx config and also your client side socketio code as well.

Comment: @v1shva I have added the code as you requested. Thank you

Comment: you will have to add ssl certs to your nginx server if you are using wss. see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/https-and-http2-nginx-config-for-socket-io

Comment: @v1shva do check my server now.

Comment: What do you see in nginx logs? Any errors?